# NextJS serverside Breakpoints possible?

Tags: next.js

Is it possible to set breakpoints in NextJS serverside code? I've got a `debugger` in my `getInitialProps` and it never breaks at that point. It only breaks when it's ran on the browser, server side breakpoints never seem to catch.

Comment: Is the breakpoint of node works on other functions?

Comment: I use VScode to debug the server-side code. Just press F5, the steps are pretty intuitive.

Comment: Checkout this video - https://youtu.be/wTmNnV72q-M

Answer (score 2):

What a beautiful question you asked!

getInitialProps It call when the component is called. Just like componentDidMount in react. The difference is that...
You must send the props it needs before calling.
Otherwise ssr will not work.

This method does not display the console and you must return and display the parameter in the method

```
static async getInitialProps = () => {
  return {custom: 'value'}
}


render() {
 return(
  <div>
   {JSON.stringify(custom)}
  </div>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this question has not been answered:

getInitialProps in nextjs is a server-side function. So, in VSCode, you will have to start the server (npm run dev) in debug mode in order to "hit" the breakpoints in the server-side code. Likewise, you may launch the client side (browser) in debug mode in order to "hit" the breakpoints in the client-side code.